# How check in what Queue a SIP id is located

Tags: python, asterisk

Hello all a quick question, i'm trying to write a simple python script so when someone calls a number the script will first check if the number is free aka 'NOT_INUSE' whenever it is in use or any other state i want to redirect the caller to the dynamic Queue he / she is part of.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
from asterisk.agi import *

def no_space(s):
  if s.endswith(' '): s = s[:-1]
  if s.startswith(' '): s = s[1:]
  return s

agi = AGI()

calledNbr = sys.argv[1]
calledNbr = no_space(calledNbr)
status = agi.get_variable('DEVICE_STATE(%(redi)s)'%{'redi':calledNbr})

if status == 'NOT_INUSE':
  agi.appexec("Dial", redirect)
else:
  ???? - redirect to Queue example: agi.appexec("Queue", "support")
```

Now i just want to know how to check in what Queue the calledNbr is located so i can redirect the call to one of his colleges.

Thanks in advance!

Best regards
Nick

Comment: Not related to your question, but you can just use `str#strip` for your `no_space` function:  `def no_space(s): return s.strip()`

Answer (score 0):

Correct way - put queue_log into database and query queue_log

Comment: Can you show me an example how this is done? i don't really understand how this would fit in my case. As i understand Queue_log just keeps logs of actions done by the queue not who is part of it? So if a dynamic queue member would log off it would not get logged here?

Comment: When dynamic member login/logoff it also log this action.